# Sqoop export is successful but destination postgres table is empty

Tags: postgresql, sqoop

I am trying to export the table from hdfs to postgres
Below is the query which I used for export:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql:hostname:5432/postgresDB --username user --password password --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --fields-terminated-by ',' --table customer --export-dir /hdfs/location/customer --input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' --direct --update-key customer_id
```

The sqoop query completes with success message. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

But when I query the table, I am not finding any data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [Sqoop Export inserts vs updates](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_inserts_vs_updates)?

Comment: Thanks Dev, I used removed update-key option and added --update-mode allowinsert option and it worked .. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Happy to help..!! you can answer your own question if you want so that others can see it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql:hostname:5432/postgresDB \
--username user \
--password password \
--input-fields-terminated-by '\001' \
--fields-terminated-by ',' \
--table customer \
--export-dir /hdfs/location/customer \
--input-null-string '\\N' --input-null-non-string '\\N' \
--direct \
--update-mode allowinsert
```

This worked ..

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked after I added the schema name for my table name.

-- -- schema my_schema